# UITextView is not resigning when added as sub view of UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, uitextview, uialertview, uikeyboard, resignfirstresponder

I've added `UITextView` as a sub view of `UIAlertView`, I've added `UIToolBar` with a Done button  (using `UIBarButtonItem`) as `inputAccessoryView` to allow user to resign keyboard`. It's just working fine in iOS6.0. And not in iOS5.0.

I've break point and checked in all the way I can, for reconfirming my self, I've made a sample project and checked the same in both the iOS versions, and the problem is same.

Here's the code, that's messing with me,

```
-(UIToolbar *)accessoryView
{
    if (!accessoryView) {
        accessoryView = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44.0)];

        UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(hideKeyBoard)];

        UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                          initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                          target:nil
                                          action:nil];

        accessoryView.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexibleSpace,btn, nil];
        [accessoryView setTintColor:[[UIColor blackColor]colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5]];
    }
    return accessoryView;
}

-(IBAction) showAlertWithTextView: (id) sender
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 200)];
    alert.title = nil;
    alert.message = nil;
    alert.delegate = self;

    //textview I've added in .h file
    textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:alert.bounds];
    textView.text = @"This is a UITextView";
    textView.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
    textView.editable = YES;
    textView.inputAccessoryView = [self accessoryView];
    [alert addSubview:textView];
    [alert show];
}

- (void)hideKeyBoard {
   [textview resignFirstResponder];
   //[self.view endEditing:YES]; //this is also not worked
}
```

Here's list of steps I'm doing,

1. Showing Alert with Textview
2. Focus to Textview
3. Tap on Done button to resign TextView
4. Its not resigning in iOS5 but resigning in iOS6

Any idea? What's going wrong?

Comment: actually what happens? Are you trying to say that after removing the alert keyboard doesnt hide. or you want to hide keyboard when alert is present there?

Comment: Please check updated question. I've added a list of steps that I'm doing.

Comment: See my answer this may help you.........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it, as solution given by @iOS Developer, but as I've so many `UIAlertView` objects to handle, I've added a property of `UIAlertView` in delegate, and assigning it with the object of my alertview like this,

```
-(void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    //set current alertview
    [[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] setCurrentAlertView:alertView];
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    //will remove current alertview reference
    [[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] setNilCurrentAlertView];
}

- (void)hideKeyBoard {

    [textView resignFirstResponder];
    //when need to resign UITextView, get current alertview object
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] getCurrentAlertView];
    if(alertView) {
        [alertView resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

In AppDelegate.m file,

```
#pragma mark - UIAlertView Resign 
- (void) setCurrentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alert{
    self.alertObj = alert;
}

- (void) setNilCurrentAlertView {
    self.alertObj = nil;
}

- (UIAlertView *)getCurrentAlertView {
    return (UIAlertView *)self.alertObj;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually your textview is not the first responder. The first responder is your alertView.

So you should try this....

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
[alertView resignFirstResponder];
```

To use this code you must declare your alertView object in your.h file

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's working! But the problem is with having object of `UIAlertView`, I've lots of `UIAlerView` already coded so for now I can't take into header file, also its working in iOS6.0

Comment: Can I get object of particular alert? +1 for your answer.

Comment: No need to declare all alerts in header. Just one alertView with text should be declared in header file.

Answer (score 0):

As it is somewhat late but I am wondering that your code will not work in iOS7 or not as from iOS7 onwards `UIAlertView` is not allowing to add any subview (As you are adding `UITextView` as subview of `UIAlertView`).

If your requirement is not to compulsory using the `UITextView` then you can use `UIAlertView` with following configuration with default textfield in alert.

```
UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"
                                                          message:@"Message"
                                                         delegate:self
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];

        [message setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
[message show];
```

And you can get value of this textfield in delegate of `UIAlertView` like this,

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
      [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Yuvi. Now I'm doing all stuff with the custom alert. :-)

Comment: what if the i want a text view instead of a text field.

Comment: You can not use TextView instead of Textfield because it is default configuration of UIAlertView, and if you want to use TextView then find some custom alert view or create your own.